# How to make a complex formula working with keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

I am still new in coding. I have to make this formula working.

GPro = 31 * ((Cr / 8.4)<sup>-1.5</sup>) * (kA<sup>-0.2</sup>) * kG

It is an online calculator that must work automatically after input from the user (keyup event). 
There are three formulas on the site - CrumPro, CrumPo and Gpro (see Codes below). First two are working just fine. However as soon as I add the third one (GPro) in the Script the other two just crashed and stop working. I do something wrong, but I can't understand what. Maybe I use wrong the Math.pow function... I need an expert advise... Or maybe a better code. As I said - the first two formulas worked fine as long the third one is not in the script.

Thanks in advance

Here are the codes:

```js
// Get CrumPro
    function getCrPro() {
      var CrmgPro= parseFloat($('#demo3').val());
      var CrumPro = CrmgPro / 0.05;
      var CrPro = CrumPro.toFixed(2);
      if (isNaN(CrPro)) CrPro = 0;
  
      $('#demo5').val((CrPro));
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#demo3').keyup(function(event) {
        getCrPro();
      });
    });

    // Get CrumPo
    function getCrPo() {
      var CrmgPo = parseFloat($("#res1").val());
      var CrumPo = CrmgPo / 0.05;
      var CrPo = CrumPo.toFixed(2);
      if (isNaN(CrPo)) CrPo = 0;
 
      $('#res2').val((CrPo));
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#res1').keyup(function(event) {
        getCrPo();
      });
    });

    //get GPro
    function getGPro () {
      var Cr = parseFloat($("#demo3").val());
      var Cru = Cr / 0.05;
      var Cru2 = Cru.toFixed(2);
      var Cr8 = Cru2 / 8.4;
      var kCr = Math.pow (Cr8, -1,5);

      var kA = parseFloat($("#demo1").val());
      var kAP = Math.pow (kA, -0,2);

      var kG = parseFloat($("#demo4").val());
 
      var G = (31 * kCr * kAP * kG);

      if (isNaN(G)) G = 0;

      $('#demo6').val((G));
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#demo3').keyup(function(event) {
        getGPro();
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="demo1" type=“number” name="age" placeholder="age">
    <label for="demo1">kA (age)</label>
    <br />
    <input id="demo2a" class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="0,742" onClick="document.getElementById('demo4').value=this.value">
    <label for="demo2a">female</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="demo2b" class="gender" value="1" onClick="document.getElementById('demo4').value=this.value">
    <label for="demo2b">male</label>
    <br />
    <input id="demo4" type="text" name="kG" placeholder="kG" readonly="true" value="0">
    <label for="demo4">kG</label>
    <br />
    <input id="demo3" type="number" name="Cr" placeholder="CrPro">
    <label for="demo3">CrPro</label>
    <br />
    <input id="demo5" type="text" name="CrumPro" readonly="true" placeholder="=CrPro/0,01131222" value="0">
    <label for="demo5"> CrumPro </label> 
    <br />
    <input id="demo6" type="text" name="GPro" readonly="true" placeholder=" GPro = 31 * ((Cr / 8.4)^-1.5) * (kA^-0.2) * kG)">
    <label for="demo6"> GPro </label>
    <br />
    <input id="res1" type="number" name="CrPo" placeholder="Crea (mg/dL)">
    <label for="res1"> CrPo </label>
    <br />
    <input id="res2" type="text" name="CrumPo" readonly="true" value="0" placeholder="= CrPo/0.01131222">
    <label for="res2">CrumPo</label>
    <br />
    <input id="res3" type="text" name="GPo" readonly="true" placeholder="GPo = 31 * ((Cr / 8.4)^-1.5) * (kA^-0.2) * kG)">
    <label for="res3">GPo</label>
```

Comment: Can you post the code in a code snippet so we can run it?

Comment: @zevee How? Give me a link or something, please.

Comment: Done. There is a message about an error, but I couldn’t find it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a typo; you missed semicolon in *getGPro* code:

```
var G = (31 * kCr * kAP * kG)
```

Must be:

```
var G = (31 * kCr * kAP * kG);
```

**UPDATE:**
Also the *getGPro* function definition has a typo. *function* must be in lowercase:

```
function getGPro ()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is still dead :(

Comment: There was one more. I wrote “Mat” instead of “Math”, but it still doesn’t work...

Comment: So fix these two issues in the snippet and we can search for other problems

Comment: @Pussyfer if the answer solved your problem plz consider accepting it as answer.

Comment: Well, your answer solve the problem from parts. The other two functions are now working, but the getGPro makes no sense. It shows only “0” as result, no matter what number I enter in “CrPro” field... that means the formula doesn’t work and I don’t know why...

Answer (score 1):

You're using `var` with a capital V in your `getGPro` function

Comment: Nop, with small “v” it is still dead. :(